Dimension of group scheme
I am new to algebraic geometry and reading group schemes and their representations from Jantzen’s book. My question id the following:

Let $G$ be a finite group and $k$ be a field. Then there exists a group scheme $\mathbf{G}$ corresponding to $G$ via the equivalence of categories category of finite algebraic $k$-groups and category of finite dimensional cocommutative Hopf algebras over $k$. Then what we can say about the dimension of the group scheme $\mathbf{G}$? Does it equal  the dimension of the Hopf algebra?

If cardinality of $G$ is $n$ then the dimension of the Hopf algebra $kG$ is $n$. So does the dimension of $\mathbf{G}$ equal $n$?

If the Hopf algebra is of finite dimension the group scheme has dimension 0.

@JonathanWise Thanks for your comment. Can you tell the reason? And what happens for infinite groups?

As Jonathan Wise mentioned in the comments, if we have a Hopf algebra $H$ over $k$ which is finite-dimensional as a $k$ vector space, then the corresponding group scheme is zero-dimensional. This is not related to the comultiplication in any way, in fact, we have the following result:
If $A$ is a finite-dimensional algebra over a field $k$, then $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ is zero-dimensional.
There are different ways to see this. One might show that $A$ is Artinian and proceed from there. More generally we have the following result:
Let $X \to Y$ be a surjective and finite (or more generally, surjective and integral) morphisms of schemes. Then $\dim X = \dim Y$.
We can apply this to the structure morphism $\operatorname{Spec}(A) \to \operatorname{Spec}(k)$.
This also tells you what happens if you associate to a finite group $G$ a group scheme over a base scheme $S$ which is more general than the spectrum of a field: the resulting group scheme will always have the same dimension as $S$.
If you allow infinite groups, then this result doesn't change. For any group $G$, the group scheme you get is $\bigsqcup_{g \in G} \operatorname{Spec}(k)$ or if you work over a more general basis $S$, then you have $\bigsqcup_{g \in G}S$. This group scheme is also called the constant group scheme over $S$ associated to $G$. Now a purely topological fact about Krull dimension is that for any collection $X_i$ of spaces, we have $\dim \bigsqcup_i X_i=\sup_{i} \dim X_i$.
Thus $\dim \bigsqcup_{g \in G} S= \dim S$ and in particular if $S=\operatorname{Spec}(k)$ for a field $k$, we get $\dim\bigsqcup_{g \in G} S=0$.
As a word of caution, here is one thing that does change for infinite groups $G$: the resulting group scheme $\bigsqcup_{g \in G} S$ is never affine if $S$ is non-empty and $G$ is infinite, because it is not quasicompact. Thus it also does not correspond to a Hopf algebra. (Only affine group schemes correspond to Hopf algebras. (If $S$ itself is non-affine, then you need to use a (quasicoherent) "sheafy" version of Hopf algebras and "relative affineness", i.e. affineness of the structure morphism to $S$. But over a field you don't need to worry about this.))

Thank you for your answer. Can you recommend some reference for your last paragraph, particularly that “sheafy” version of Hopf algebra?

I don't have a reference to be honest,I just figured out this stuff on my own
